# Index & match with multiple rows and columns - return the cell below

Tags: excel

I'm trying to return a value from the cell below the value that I'm looking for. I tried to use index and match but it didn't work for me. the table is similar to this one below

[image: this is the picture of the table]

So for example I have a cell in another sheet that has the value 'P'. What I want to do is to search for this value and return the value of the cell below it which is in this case '11'.

Note: the table has no headings.

Comment: are the items to be searched unique?

Comment: Yes they are unique

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use INDEX with two AGGREGATE:

```
=INDEX(A1:E6,AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW(A1:E6)-MIN(ROW(A1:E6))+1)/(A1:E6=H2),1)+1,AGGREGATE(15,7,(COLUMN(A1:E6)-MIN(COLUMN(A1:E6))+1)/(A1:E6=H2),1))
```

[image]

---

For those with access to the Dynamic Array formula `LET` we can lessen the number of times the ranges are referred to:

```
=LET(rng,A1:E6,lkpVal,H2,INDEX(rng,AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW(rng)-MIN(ROW(rng))+1)/(rng=lkpVal),1)+1,AGGREGATE(15,7,(COLUMN(rng)-MIN(COLUMN(rng))+1)/(rng=lkpVal),1)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much that is exactly what I want. I appreciate your help

Comment: What abount `Sumproduct` like `=INDEX(A1:E6,SUMPRODUCT(ROW(A1:E6)*(A1:E6="P"))+1,SUMPRODUCT(COLUMN(A1:E6)*(A1:E6="P")))`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Sumproduct()` with `Index()`.

```
=INDEX(A1:E6,SUMPRODUCT(ROW(A1:E6)*(A1:E6="P"))+1,SUMPRODUCT(COLUMN(A1:E6)*(A1:E6="P")))
```

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: This is about our tool esProc. It’s an easier way to solve this problem.

```
A1 = =clipboard().import@t() //copy the Data area in Excel,then import from the clipboard
A2 = A1.split@n("\t")
A3 = A2.step(2,1).conj()
A4 = A2.step(2,2).conj()
A5 = A3.(~+"\t"+A4(#)).concat@n() //Paste the results to Excel
```

More explaination,see [Convert a Multi-row-based Table to a Regular Row-wise Table](http://c.raqsoft.com/article/1608029749665)